# MSMQ private queue issue between two domains

Tags: msmq

My local machine is on domain A, my simple console application tries to put a message onto a private queue of a remote machine, which is on domain B. In the outgoing queues the status shows connected but the message does not seem to go. On the receiving side, the private queue does not seem to be receiving the message. The permissions for the private queue is set to full control for Everyone,Anonymous log in and System.

Comment: do you get any exceptions? I assume your console app runs under an domain account from domain A? Is there a trust between domain A and domain B?

Comment: There won't be any exceptions; the message has gone into the outgoing queue so the send() was 100% successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Impersonate to the user for domainb first (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joncole/archive/2009/09/21/impersonation-code-in-c.aspx)

and then make the call(s) to the remote queue

Not 100% sure if that will work though.

Comment: would using <identity impersonate="true" userName="domainB\username" password="password"> help?

Comment: If it was a permissions issue, MSMQ would discard the message on delivery. Also, security is wide open so not a permissions problem. More likely is that acknowledgements are not returning from the remote machine to allow the message to flow. Need more detail - are queues transactional, etc.

Comment: The queues are not transactional, what other info would you like me to provide?

Comment: Is it because of trusting not happening that the message is not sent or acknowledgments are not received. But my outgoing queues just say 'connected and waiting for transfer'.

Comment: No, trusts just affect access - the message will either be delivered or discarded. No limbo situation of connected but undelivered. Looking at a network trace may help - could be a badly configured firewall, for example, preventing proper flow of packets.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with NAT, if the receiver machine is behind a NAT, you can not send MQ to it.
The work around is to specify a public IP on the receiver machine and use direct TCP address format which is 'FormatName:DIRECT=TCP:{remoteIP}\private$\{QueueName}'

Forexample:

FormatName:DIRECT=TCP:200.201.202.203\private$\mqReceiverQueue